# Error resolving localhost:4200 while trying to serve angular application

Tags: angular, typescript

On running `ng serve` command browser shows this:

> Error resolving "localhost:4200" ("") for "10.238.0.0": rpc
> error: code = Unknown desc = no such record

Sorry If the question is simple, I'm new to angular.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would advise you to describe your problem in some more details, for example, which URL are you trying to resolve, what are you trying to do when this error happens, etc.

Comment: @MarkiianBenovskyi After making a new project in Angular CLI, I ran `ng serve` in terminal. It shows 'Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200'. But when I open my browser(firefox) it shows this error.  Then I tried `ng serve -o` , and it opened in edge but still not opening in firefox.

Comment: Which version of angular cli do you use? Type ng --version in the terminal.

Comment: @zgue  Oh! I got the error ... When your pc is connected to a VPN then browser will give this error if you run `ng-serve`...though it was opening in edge but firefox was giving error. After removing VPN error was resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to turn off your VPN.
And your problem should go away

Comment: I had v14 angular app and it worked well with VPN. Yesterday, I upgraded it to v15 and I am getting this error on the browser.  So I turned off the VPN and it starts working. Why doe the v15 angular not work with VPN?

Comment: Check if your VPN has any specific network configurations or restrictions that could interfere with Angular v15. Some VPNs have settings or policies that might impact certain web applications.